# Slick and filtering by Option columns

Tags: scala, slick, scalaquery

I'm trying to filter against an optional date column with Scala Slick 1.0.1.

It may be I just don't see it, but I've got a table that looks something like this:

```
case class UserRole(id:UUID, userID:UUID, role:String)
object UserRole extends Table[UserRole]("User_Role")  {

  //(id: Long = 0l, name: String, active: Boolean) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {
  def id = column[UUID]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def userID = column[UUID]("user_id")
  def vendorID = column[UUID]("vendor_id")
  def role = column[String]("role")
  def user = foreignKey("user_FK", userID, User)(_.id)

  def start = column[java.sql.Date]("startDate")
  def endDate = column[Option[java.sql.Date]]("endDate")

  def * = id ~ userID ~ role  <> (UserRole.apply _, UserRole.unapply _)
}
```

You'll see there that the endDate is optional.

How do I construct a query where I filter so endDate can be NULL/None or greater than the current (db) date?  FYI, I'm generally using the embedded api

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not pretty (the part about `null.asInstanceOf`), but I think it will work.  I got that idea from an old Scala Query post, so I don't know if slick ever put something better in for that, but when I looked at the resulting `selectStatement` from the query, it looked correct:

```
val now = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
val query = for {
  role <- UserRole
  if (role.endDate === null.asInstanceOf[Option[java.sql.Date]] || role.endDate > now)
} yield role
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment by @MartinKolinek, this code will also work and is much cleaner and probably the better way to do things:

```
val now = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
val query = for {
  role <- UserRole
  if (role.endDate.isNull || role.endDate > now)
} yield role
```

Comment: I think we should add isEmpty to the Slick API so we conform to the Scala Option API.

Comment: What's the Slick 3.0 way to check if an `Option[A]` column equals some `A`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith, I'm not using slick 3.0 yet, but a quick look at the `OptionColumnExtensionMethods` api doc (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.2/api/index.html#slick.lifted.OptionColumnExtensionMethods) reveals things like `===`, `>=`, etc... that seem like the operators to use in queries for comparisons